# Transfer data service (0x36) not sending pending in UDS

Tags: uds

I'm trying to understand why the server is not sending 0x78 NRC.
for example the client send 0x36 to server and the server should send 0x78 to client if the final response is not ready in less that 25 ms but, the response(NRC 0x24) is in 180 ms.

What I found is that the final NRC is under 20 ms if I calculate from the acknowledgement  not from the request and i know the real time is not really the time for p2server max is delta (the time for the request to arrive successfully to server and the response from the server)
What I want to know is if pending should be sent to client before ack or after cuz I think the time starts after ack.

Comment: In UDS, P2 and P2* timings are session and ECU specific.

Comment: The default value of P2 timeout (P2server_max) equals to 50ms, not 20ms (you can check it in ISO-14229-1) and as @DrMickeyLauer wrote, it is session specific. P2server is measured from the moment when a request is fully delivered (so after ACK of the last packet carrying request if you use CAN bus) till the first response packet transmission is started. So as you pointed out, the timeout has not be exceeded in your example.